# Parent tweet id using reply tweet's id

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Lets say I have the id of a tweet which is a reply to another tweet. How to get the id of this parent tweet using tweepy in python.

Comment: What code have you tried? What version of the Twitter API are you using? Please provide more context and information in order for the community to help you. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

First, use tweepy to get the tweet you have the id for. If it is a reply, its `in_reply_to_status_id` property will be set (otherwise it will be `None`).

```
import tweepy

from config import *

# OAuth process, using the keys and tokens
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

tweet_id = 1556276424662831104

tweet = api.get_status(tweet_id)
print(tweet.in_reply_to_status_id) # prints the parent status id

parent_tweet = tweet = api.get_status(tweet.in_reply_to_status_id)
print(parent_tweet)
print(parent_tweet.in_reply_to_status_id) # prints None
```